# Insert from multiple tables

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert data from 3 tables that holds data from CSV files into a meaningful warehouse table but don't know if my syntax is correct.

```
insert into warehouseTBL
select a.recordNum, b.fieldA, b.fieldB, c.fieldC, c.fieldD,
  from ctrTable a, tableB b, tableC c
 where a.recordNum = b.recordNum
   and a.recordNum = c.recordNum
   and a.someField = b.someField
   and a.someField = c.someField
```

So should I use a nested select in the From clause so it look something like this:

```
  from ctrTable a, (
        select *
          from tableB, tableC,
         where tableB.recNum = tableC.recNum
       ) as d,
 where a.recNum      = d.recNum
```

Does the syntax even make sense?

Comment: Put respective oracle error in the question.

Comment: The syntax looks OK, although 1) it is preferable to explicitly list the columns on the insert table "insert into warehouseTBL(recordnum, fieldA, fieldB ...)" and 2) use ANSI joins in your select viz from ctrTable a inner join tableB b on a.recordNum = b.Recordnum etc.

Comment: @zerkms: The first statement didn't generate any Oracle errors but I can't create a unique index on the warehouseTBL. I removed the Oracle tag since it's more a SQL syntax issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use this query to insert the rows,

```
insert into warehouseTBL
select recordNum, fieldA, fieldB, fieldC,fieldD from 
(select a.recordNum, b.fieldA, b.fieldB, c.fieldC, c.fieldD,
  from ctrTable a, tableB b, tableC c
 where a.recordNum = b.recordNum
   and a.recordNum = c.recordNum
   and a.someField = b.someField
   and a.someField = c.someField)p
```

Comment: I assume `select *fields from ctrTbl c, (select *fields from tblA a, tblB b where a.recNum = b.recNum AND a.area = b.area) d where c.recNum = d.recNum AND c.area=d.area` would work?

Comment: i m not sure about that as it will means as the same as you have posted in your question.